# No Image change - css

Tags: css, hover

What's wrong with this code? When i tried it with border-style, border-with, so it works. but it doesn't work with background-Image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style type = 'text/css'>
    a.test:hover span{
        background-image: url('bearbeitenx.png');
    }

    //.test { background-image:url('unbenannt.png');}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<a href = 'eerwerqwerwer' class = 'test'><span style = 'background-image: url(bearbeiten1.png); width:40px; height:40px; display: block; background-repeat: no-repeat;' ></span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And why doesn't work this?

Answer (score 1):

`.bearbeiten1-png a:hover` matches a hovered anchor element that is a descendant of an element that is a member of the bearbeiten1-png class.

You have no such element.

`a.bearbeiten1-png:hover` would match your anchor, but you probably still wouldn't see a difference because your `<img>` element is likely to cover up the background image.

Comment: is it possible to Chance scr with css?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the CSS selector should be `a.bearbeiten1-png:hover`.  Your current CSS is applying that hover style to an `a` that is a descendant of an element classed as `bearbeiten1-png`.  That doesn't match how your HTML is structured.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/gn5mfpww/3/

This will work with

```
a.bearbeiten1-png:hover{
    background-image:     url('http://www.galliano.cc/Test_seite/cms/uploads/bearbeitenx.png');
}
```

Moved the image to little right to see if the background image is forming or not .